# Set a minimal default range for a column chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts for a column chart that has positive and negative percentage values.

I always want the y-axis of the chart to display at least the range between -50% and +30%, no matter what the values are. However, if a value is larger than 30% or small than -50% the range of the y-axis should adapt accordingly.  if I use `yAxis: {min: -50, max: 30}` the range won't get bigger when I have larger values.

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to update it programmatically once Highcharts has calculated the range?

Comment: There is a feature request for this functionality here:  http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/1848953-extend-the-axis-max-property-to-act-like-css-mi  Please vote and comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have to do it yourself.
It can be accomplished by running a function to check the min/max and reset if needed.

Something like this (quick dirty example):

```
function setMinAxisExtremes(chart, axis, min, max) {
    var ax = axis == 'y' ? chart.yAxis[0] : chart.xAxis[0];    
    var ext = ax.getExtremes();
    min = ext.min > min ? min : ext.min;    
    max = ext.max < max ? max : ext.max;
    ax.setExtremes(min,max);    
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/szub0o3g/

(and as noted above, there is a feature request to have Highcharts do this with a built in property, which is sorely in need of votes, here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/1848953-extend-the-axis-max-property-to-act-like-css-mi )

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was also doing something alike in the meantime. I sure hope that at some point it'll be supported directly by Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your own function to position ticks, it is [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner)

Comment: I don't think I can use this for my issue, as it only defines where the ticka are laid out but not how the range is defined. Or am I missing something?